# Is a plumbing fitting in a drain pipe likely to cause clogs?

Tags: flange

Had a leaky shark bite so I took off the toilet to better access it.  It flew off, hit me, and dropped into the flange hole (I know should have put a rag in there). Will it just roll into the septic? This toilet is the last one in the house about 40 feet from the septic.

Comment: is it large enough to jam in the pipe?

Comment: Please post  the approx dimensions of the connector

Comment: A "shark bite" isn't a thing--it's a brand covering a wide range of products. Please revise to be more specific about exactly what's in your plumbing. Use generic industry terms and a specific size.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how small it is and what slope (gradient) you have in your pipe.  It could stay there and snag bits going by and create a block.  No one can predict.

Suggestion, if you are able to see the entry pipe into your septic tank, get someone to flush the toilet and immediately empty a bucket of water in it, to increase the flow.  Try it a few times and see if comes out the end.